# How to convert object to map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following object, it needs to be converted into a map in dart for flutter:

```
{option1: {optionValue: 'Yes', optionId: `${match.id}`+ '333'+ `1`}, option2:{optionValue: 'No', optionId: `${match.id}`+ '333'+ `2` }}
```

Comment: it is already a map, but for cast you can do,  Map<String, dyanmic> myMap= {option1: {optionValue: 'Yes', optionId: `${match.id}`+ '333'+ `1`}, option2:{optionValue: 'No', optionId: `${match.id}`+ '333'+ `2` }}

Comment: ok, how do i loop through it and collect data in "optionValue"?

Comment: If it's in json format you could use jsonDecode() ; 
For optionValue in loop use index as myMap[i][0]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here is a working solution:

```
void main() {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> myMap = [
    {
      'option1': {'optionValue': 'Yes', 'optionId': 1}
    },
    {
      'option2': {'optionValue': 'No', 'optionId': 2}
    }
  ];
  
  final myOptionValue = myMap.map((el) => el[el.keys.first]['optionValue']).toList();  
  print(myOptionValue);
}
```

It prints [Yes, No]